# Problem to get output file after signhash

Tags: c#

I have signature after signing pdf file with method:

`var signature = privateKey.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);`

Now i'm trying attack this signature to pdf file (the signed source file), anyone have any way? i'm stuck here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem to write a byte array of a signed hash with a private key to a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867806/problem-to-write-a-byte-array-of-a-signed-hash-with-a-private-key-to-a-pdf-file)

Comment: I mean:  file source --> signhash --> result file (signed), i dont know how to get that result file

Comment: @paulsm4 its not